# Get data from backend into three columns in one row

Tags: php, html-table

I am making a function in which the data I am trying to get comes in `two columns` in `one row` and there are multiple rows generated. The data is arranged in table and I tried to make the table with `three columns` instead of `two` but its not working out. Sometimes in some rows it skips one column and sometimes it output perfect 3 columns in one row. I below code works perfect for `two columns` in each row, but how to make data appear in `three column` in one row ?

```
$r = 1;
$html = "";
$html .= '<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody><tr>';
    foreach($products as $pr) {
        if($r != 1) {$rw = (bool)($r & 1);
        $html .= $rw ? '</tr><tr>' : ''; }
            $html .= '<td><strong>'.$pr->name.'</strong><br>'.'<strong>Rs '.$pr->price.'</strong><br>'.$this->product_barcode($pr->code, 30, 147).'</td>';
        $r++;
    } 
$html .= '</tr></tbody>
</table>';

$data['html'] = $html;
```

Here is the output screenshot. Its coming in 2 columns in one row. I want 3 columns in one row.

[image: See its coming in 2 columns I want this in 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :) Modulus operator helps here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

```
$html = '<table class="table table-bordered"><table>';
$r = 0;
$columns = 3;
foreach ($products as $pr) {
    if ($r%$columns == 0) $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td>';
    $html .= '<strong>'.$pr->name.'</strong><br />';
    $html .= $pr->price.'<br />';
    $html .= $this->product_barcode($pr->code, 30, 147);
    $html .= '</td>';
    if ($r%$columns == $columns || $r++ == count($products)-1) $html .= '</tr>';
}
$html .= '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: Sorry but all of those values (name , price , barcode) will be in one <td> and there will be 3 <td> in one row and there will be many rows . I was able to make it work out for 2 <td> in on row but not 3

Comment: Sorry - I am finding it hard to understand exactly what you mean then. Are you able to provide a var_dump of your $products array?

Comment: 1 min i will upload a screenshot

Comment: I have added screenshot . It will help us both to convey and understand

Comment: Ahhh - thanks, that makes sense. Give me a couple of minutes :)

Comment: LOL thanks to you . You'r the one helping me out with your precious time . Thank you

Comment: thank you for the answer but its not working at the moment . I am trying to find out why

Comment: I found the typo and fixed it . I guess you wanted me to search for it . LOL . If yes thank you for the puzzle as well as the answer .

Comment: Haha - no, I'm not that mean :) I just had a mistake because I didn't test before I posted. Thanks for accepting answer anyway. I've updated answer with working code, and included a simple variable to change the number of columns to display.

Comment: Haha Just kidding . Thank you so much for you time .