# php mysql data base retrieval three records in one row

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and mysql to retrieve databases records

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $id = $row["id"];
            $title = $row["title"];
            $search_output .= "<div class='container'>
    <div class='col-md-12' style='margin: 20px 40px 20px 40px;'>

                <div class='content-heading'>
                    <h2>$title</h2>
                </div>
                <div class='content-tags'>

                    <a href='#'>#song</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";
                } // close while loop
```

As it shows here in `$query`, I selected the table to retrieve the data and put it in `$search_output` ,so that each retrieved record will have the same form, my problem is something close to [get data from backend into three columns in one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060063/get-data-from-backend-into-three-columns-in-one-row)

I want three records in one row. But the difference that `$search_output` is not an array, I just want `$search_output` which represent one record,
to be shown as three records in one row. because i need it to look as 2 rows and each row 3 records(column), and I only have one variable for that is `$search_output` .

I tried to write this to show what i want but it doesn't work

```
<table>


 <?php


 $r = 0;
 $columns = 3;
 foreach($search_output as $s){
    if($r%$columns == 0) $html .="<tr>";
    $html .= "<td>";
     echo $search_output;
     $html .="</td>";
     if ($r%$columns == $columns || $r++ == count($search_output)-1) $html .= "</tr>";
}



 ?>

</table>
```

this is the screenshot :[image]

but it looks like that when i write

```
<table><tr><td> <?php echo $search_result; ?> </td></tr></table>
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: you want to match with 3 columns in database??

Comment: $search_output retrieves the records, i want in one row  three records horizontally

Comment: I tried that but it look each record in one row  ...

Comment: <table>


 <?php

 
 $r = 0;
 $columns = 3;
 foreach($search_output as $s){
    if($r%$columns == 0) $html .="<tr>";
 $html .= "<td>";
  echo $search_output;
  $html .="</td>";
  if ($r%$columns == $columns || $r++ == count($search_output)-1) $html .= "</tr>";
}

           

 ?>

</table>

Comment: this is how i tried, but it doesn't work.

Comment: show the screenshot how ur getting

Comment: When i'm using the last code it doesn't work, but when i write just<div> <?php echo $search_result ?></div>

Comment: I updated me question with a screenshot,, thank you

Comment: check the below answer once, it shud work or can you give link to server for this page??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using BOOTSTRAP wrong.

First after the **container** DIV  the **row** DIV is missing.

And if you want to have three columns then **col-md-12** must be **col-md-4**

12 = full column,  4 = three columns  (12/3 = 4) 
Check Bootstrap Dokumentation for more details.

```
  <div class='container'>
   <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4'></div>
    <div class='col-md-4'></div>
    <div class='col-md-4'></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

and

```
$search_output = "<div class='container'><div class='row'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $title = $row["title"];
        $search_output .= "
<div class='col-md-4' style='margin: 20px 40px 20px 40px;'>
            <div class='content-heading'>
                <h2>$title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class='content-tags'>
                <a href='#'>#song</a>
            </div>
        </div>";
            } 
$search_output .= '</div></div>';
```

But this is only working if **3** rows are fetched from **DB**

Comment: No, i don't it is bootstrap, i tried this one you are talking about , but it shows exactly the same as <table><tr><td><?php echo $search_output?></td></tr></table>    .... and repeating div will repeat the records ,,,sorry but that doesn't work

Comment: the above answer shud work for you. its working for me. checked just now.

Comment: but what to write inside divs ? it should  be <?php $search_output; ?>  and if i write that inside each div it will repeat the records three times

Comment: Then you mabe have an CSS Style Problem. And for that you are telling to less information. Why do you do **style='margin: 20px 40px 20px 40px;'** and why using **<div class='content-heading'>**. You should try it first without inner 'DIV' , test it with : <div class='col-md-4'>$title</div>  and from that add step by step new CSS and HTML-Code.

Comment: **I only have one variable for that is $search_output** ... in PHP you can create **variables** as you will, at any place. ;)

Comment: Thank you statelessMind, the front-end was not written by me, i fixed its error as you said it's bootstrap col-md and margin problems